# Object expression, interface implementation, verbose syntax

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#

I frequently use verbose syntax to create one-line expressions that would normally be several lines.  Usually I do this so I can send the whole expression to F# interactive with `Alt+'`.  For example, I might do this:

```
let longLength list = let rec helper result = function [] -> result | _ :: t -> helper (result + 1L) t in helper 0L list
```

For the example code, assume that these namespaces have been opened:

```
open System
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic
```

I want to translate this object expression to a single line:

```
let emptyEnumerator = {
    new IEnumerator<int> with member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException())
    interface IEnumerator with
        member t.MoveNext() = false
        member t.Reset() = ()
        member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException())
    interface IDisposable with member t.Dispose() = ()
    }
```

I have found that I can only do it using verbose syntax.  Normally, verbose-syntax code also compiles under light syntax, but here, it does not.  I also tried creating a named class with the same implementation, and that nearly-identical code does compile both under light and verbose syntax:

```
open System
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic

#light "off"
type A() = class interface IEnumerator<int> with member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException()) end interface IEnumerator with member t.MoveNext() = false member t.Reset() = () member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException()) end interface IDisposable with member t.Dispose() = () end end
let b = { new IEnumerator<int> with member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException()) end interface IEnumerator with member t.MoveNext() = false member t.Reset() = () member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException()) end interface IDisposable with member t.Dispose() = () end end }

#light "on"
type C() = class interface IEnumerator<int> with member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException()) end interface IEnumerator with member t.MoveNext() = false member t.Reset() = () member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException()) end interface IDisposable with member t.Dispose() = () end end
let d = { new IEnumerator<int> with member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException()) end interface IEnumerator with member t.MoveNext() = false member t.Reset() = () member t.Current = raise(InvalidOperationException()) end interface IDisposable with member t.Dispose() = () end end }
```

Both class definitions succeed, but the last line fails with "~vsB756.fsx(29,150): error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'member' in expression. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token."

The problem seems to be in the series of member definitions.  Visual Studio highlights the second and third `member` keywords in the `IEnumerator` part of the definition as the reasons for the FS0010 error.  (In other words, the highlighted `member` keywords are the ones that introduce the definitions of `IEnumerator.Reset()` and `IEnumerator.Current`.)

Visual Studio also reports errors on "let" (incomplete value or function definition), on the open brace (unmatched '{'), and on the `end` keyword before the `IDisposable` implementation, but I suspect that this is because of its failure to recognize the three members in the `IEnumerator` implementation, which causes it to try to parse the additional members as part of the definition of the first member.

Have I overlooked something in the syntax?  Is this a bug in the compiler?

Comment: This annoys me too, but not because of F# interactive. Why use only one line? You can select multiple lines and use Alt+Return to run them in the interactive console. *This example measures over 300 columns! This won't be good for readability.*

Comment: @Vandroiy Because if I have a series of single-line expressions, I can send them to interactive with one keystroke each. Besides, this being interactive, it's almost certainly a one-off; it isn't designed to be read.

Comment: @Vandroiy ... but I have indeed overlooked something, which was `Alt+Enter` for sending multiple lines to interactive.  I've been using the mouse and right-clicking to do that, but the context menu only indicates the `Alt+'` shortcut for single lines.  Perhaps with that knowledge I'll be able to have both convenience and readability.  In any event, I thank you for informing me of the shortcut.  (Where did you learn about it?)  Even without a practical motivation for this question, however, I'd still like to know the answer.

Comment: @phoog to be honest, I don't blame the compiler :).